# HTTP ERROR 500 when using GET or POST

Tags: php

Here's my PHP:

```
<?php
$userTimeZone=$_GET('timezone');
//$userTimeZone=$_POST('timezone');
$date=gmdate();
$date=date_create($date, new DateTimeZone("GMT"))
->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($userTimeZone))->format("U");
echo $date;
?>
```

I get error 500 when I use `$_GET` or `$_POST` but otherwise (using hard coded timezone) it's working fine. It isn't the problem with the GET or POST value as the problem persists if I use hard coded timezone without removing GET or POST commands. Need help. Thanks!

Comment: does your timezone from $_GET('timezone') from a form ?

Comment: where you want to POST it?

Comment: why not just use like this date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

Comment: Thanks guys, but it's just a silly mistake. Syntax error. I shouldn't have come here with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

> $_GET An associative array of variables passed to the current script
>   via the URL parameters

You're using:

```
$_GET('timezone');
```

is a not the right form to access an array.
It should be:

```
$_GET['timezone'];
```

Comment: * *facepalm* * How could I even! Thanks @DucFilan. My question deserves to be down voted.

Comment: Maybe you need to relax a little bit then get back to work awesome.

Comment: Right. I'm off.